# Does Android LocaltionManager use Google Map API to get city name?

Tags: android, google-maps

LocaltionManager in android.location package can get the current Location which contains the country name and city name.

I wonder LocationManager uses Google Map API .

If yes, it's odd. Because I'm in China. You know, in China no Google service is available.

If not, so what service does LocationManager use?

Answer (score 0):

After capturing and analyzing the internet traffic of my Android device. I found that LocationManager uses Baidu Map API, which is widely used in China.

So I think the Android ROM maker (my device runs an OS called flyme based on Android) changes that API.